# creating a folder in android issue

Tags: android

i;m trying to create a folder in the android under the sdcard directory, here is my code

```
    File folder = new File("/sdcard/"+ "testFolder");

    if (!folder.exists())
    {
        folder.mkdirs();
        Log.i("Sound folder", "Sound Folder created..");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Sound folder", "Sound Folder already exists");
    }
```

and i set the permission in the android manifest.xml, here it is :

```
<uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but when check for the folder i cant find it !! am i missing something

Answer (score 1):

`File` will not create the folder.  Checkout `mkDirs()`

```
folder.mkDirs();
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

You should not be using "/sdcard".  Instead, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "testFolder");
```

Comment: sorry it was a typo it's already in the original code , i edited my post

Comment: Is your sdcard definitely mounted at `/sdcard`?  In any case, you should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`  See my edit.

Comment: thanks worked successfully , what if i want to create folder on the internal memory ? what will be the path in this case ?

Comment: getFilesDir().  Please accept the answer so that future visitors may find it.